# What does "192.168.1.1/21" mean?

Tags: networking, network-programming, ip

When they write a slash followed by a number after an IP address, what does that mean?

Comment: Read up on "slash notation" in http://www.ripe.net/internet-coordination/press-centre/understanding-ip-addressing

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The part after the slash is how many subnet mask bits to use. Since the use of classless routing you use slash instead of saying class A or B whatever. Example:

```
192.168.1.1/24 is 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
```

`255.255.255.0` is using `24` of the `32 bits` to create the subnet.

in binary it looks like this:

```
11111111.11111111.11111111.00000000
```

so a `/30` would look like:

```
255.255.255.252 or in binary 
11111111.11111111.11111111.11111100
```

the remaing 00 is for hosts; the 1's are the network.

Answer (score 10):

It's [CIDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIDR_notation) notation for a [subnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork#Determining_the_network_prefix).

The /21 denotes that the first (most-significant) 21 bits are common to all addresses in the subnet.  The individual hosts in the network have addresses that are different only in the last 11 bits.